# How to pass Map between testCases using properties

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

I want to do the following in SOAPUI using Groovy:

In a TestCase1 select values (Lastname, firstname) from database, and create a `Map` with dynamic values: `def Map = [Login :"$Login", Nom: "$Nom"]`

I need my map to be transferred to another TestCase, for this 
I'm trying to put my map into properties:

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "Map", Map)
```

But I have error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestCasePro.setPropertyValue() is
>   applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String,
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [OuvInfoPersoMap,
>   [Login:dupond0001, Nom:Dupond]] Possible solutions:
>   setPropertyValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.String),
>   getPropertyValue(java.lang.String) error at line: 123

I found some posts on internet that suggests to use `metaClass` groovy property

```
context.testCase.metaClass.map = Map
log.info context.testCase.map
```

But I don't think it enough in my case.

I would like to be able to pass a map to Testcase2 using:

```
createMap = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites.testCases["TestCase1"] 
createMap.map
```

Hopefully you can help me solving this problem.

Thanks advance

Comment: I am not sure what your use case is. General practise that test case should be independent. Can you please tell what your use case is ? Also, do you just want only the two values or more?  By the way, a map can't be set as value into test case property.

Comment: It is only possible if you can run `first test case` using groovy script of `second test case` using the context, they way you mentioned. But not thru the properties.

Comment: Instead of map, you can set each property as String value.

Comment: In my TestCase2 I need get Map from TestCase1  which I have to convert to bean object.

Comment: I know it's possible to send each property, but it'is not solution for me, I need to set Map and i wich to change  of objects with the as keyword in Groovy , but in another groovy testCase I can get it using context

Comment: I want more than two values and not only of string type

Comment: Wee, I already mentioned in 2nd comment. Do you want that how to implement?

Comment: The first thing you need to keep in mind, is that in SoapUI _everything_ is a String! If you read the error carefully, you will notice the signature for the method is `setPropertyValue(Strig propertyName, String value)`.

Answer (score 1):

As @SiKing correctly explain in the comments, `setPropertyValue` method expects and `String` for the property name and for the property value.

Note that as @Rao suggest in general *testCase* execution should be independent, however despiste this technically it's possible to do what you ask for.

So a possible solution for your case is in the first *testCase* to serialize the `Map` to `String` in order that it's possible to save using `setPropertyValue(Strig propertyName, String value)` method, and then in the second *testCase* deserialitze it, something like the follow code must work:

## TestCase 1

Serialize the map using [`inspect()` method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#inspect()) and save it as a property:

```
def map = ['foo':'foo','bar':'bar', 'baz':'baz']
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('map',map.inspect())
```

## TestCase2

Deserialitze the `String` property using [`Eval.me(String exp)`:](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html#me(java.lang.String)):

```
// get the first testCase
def testCase1 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["TestCase1"] 
// get the property
def mapAsStr = testCase1.getPropertyValue('map')
// deserialize the string as map
def map = Eval.me(mapAsStr)
assert map.foo == 'foo'
assert map.bar == 'bar'
assert map.baz == 'baz'
```